# Odd behavior with Jupyter notebook and virtual environment

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, virtualenv, jupyter

I installed the anaconda python distribution on Ubuntu 16-04 (LTS release) and I want to use virtual environments with jupyter notebooks but I get some odd behavior:

```
conda update conda

conda create -n myvirtenv python=3.6 anaconda

conda activate myvirtenv
```

added virtual enviroment to jupyter

```
python -m ipykernel install --user –name=myvirtenv
```

When I start a jupyter notebook from my *default* enviroment and get the python version:

```
import sys

print(sys.version)
3.7.4 (default, Aug 13 2019, 20:35:49) 
[GCC 7.3.0]
```

That is as expected but when I go to **Kernel > change kernel** and select *myvirtenv* I get the same output.

When I activate *myvirtenv* and start jupyter notebook with default kernel I get the following output:

```
print(sys.version)
3.6.10 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jan  7 2020, 21:14:29) 
[GCC 7.3.0]
```

When I change to kernel to *myvirtenv* I get the following output:

```
print(sys.version)
3.7.4 (default, Aug 13 2019, 20:35:49) 
[GCC 7.3.0]
```

I would expect that when I start jupyter notebook from either the *default* environment or *myvirtenv* select the kernel myvirtenv it would use python 3.6.10 and the default kernel would use python 3.7.4? What can I do to ensure that kernel *myvirtenv* uses the correct virtual environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it:

kernel.json file was pointing to wrong python:

```
{
 "argv": [
  "/home/****/anaconda3/bin/python",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "display_name": "myvirtenv",
 "language": "python"
}
```

Changed it to:

```
{
 "argv": [
  "/home/****/anaconda3/envs/myvirtenv/bin/python",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "display_name": "myvirtenv",
 "language": "python"
}
```